# Grep a gzipped file?

Tags: unix, gzip

I would like to see if there is a `title` url in the following gzip file:

```
curl -O http://www.imdb.com/sitemap_US_02002.xml.gz
grep 'imdb.com/title/tt' sitemap_US_02002.xml.gz
```

Is there a way to do this 'on the fly', perhaps even in a one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you just want to do this in a pipelined fashion, this should work:

```
curl http://www.imdb.com/sitemap_US_02002.xml.gz | zcat | grep 'imdb.com/title/tt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Many systems (Linux and OS X at least) come with a `zgrep` utility that will gzip-decompress its input and then run the result through `grep`. Like so:

```
curl http://www.imdb.com/sitemap_US_02002.xml.gz | zgrep 'imdb.com/title/tt'
```